# DataFrameGroupBy select subset using multiindex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

2 exactly similar structured dataframes. I group them each by columns A and B.

```
dfgrouby1=df1.groupby(['A','B'])
dfgrouby2=df2.groupby(['A','B'])
```

I iterate through `dfgrouby1` by subgroup (which are each dataframes), and want to get subgroups (dataframes) with the same indices (iA,iB) from `dfgrouby2`.

**2 Questions**

1. how to retrieve the corresponding subgroup in dfgrouby2;
2. how to catch if the (iA,iB) index doesn't exist in dfgrouby2.

The loop works fine, and documentation shows dataframes with multiindices use .loc[(index tuple)], but apparently not DataFrameGroupBy objects.

Searched extensively. Maybe not using the correct descriptors.

```
for (iA,iB),eachgroup1 in dfgrouby1:
    eachgroup2 =dfgrouby2.loc[(iA,iB)]
    #do things with eachgroup1['C':'Q'] vs. eachgroup2['C':'Q'] 

AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Also tried:

```
    eachgroup2 =dfgrouby2[[iA,iB]]
KeyError: "Columns not found: 204, 34"
OR
    eachgroup2 =dfgrouby2[(iA,iB)]
KeyError: "Columns not found: 204, 34"
```

note: 204, 34 are the first values of iA,iB

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're looking for. DataFrameGroupBy is an _indexer_ it is simply a mechanism to quickly access specific groups of indices in the restricted window order of the grouping. Generally you should subset or select _before_ grouping if you'd like to operate only on a section.

Comment: Ok - so how would that apply above? I don't know what groups I'm indexing over in df2 until I group df1. TIA

Answer (score 0):

get_group is the statement I couldn't find. This pulls the corresponding group from the 2nd groupby. And a simple try/except will suffice.

```
for (iA,iB),eachgroup1 in dfgrouby1:
     try:
          eachgroup2 =dfgrouby2.get_group(iA,iB)
          #comparison code for eachgroup1 and eachgroup2
     except:
          #missing statement/or exception code
```